# Event Espresso API is missing permissions

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

#### Background

My client has a WordPress site which uses Event Espresso.

It exposes an API to serve up many events which can be seen [here](http://www.childcareoptions.ca/wp-json/ee/v4.8.36/events).

But there is one upcoming event which isn't in the array. When I try to access it directly ([address](http://www.childcareoptions.ca/wp-json/ee/v4.8.36/events/8155)), I get:

```
{
    "code": "rest_user_cannot_read",
    "message": "Sorry, you cannot read this event. Missing permissions are: ee_read_events,ee_read_others_events,ee_read_private_events",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

Note that I can access other events like that no problem.

I can see it on the frontend, and it's sold out, but I don't think that is the problem because I temporarily raised the max number of tickets so it wasn't sold out anymore... but the problem persisted.

I've compared it to other events countless times and I can't figure out what else is different. It's not set to private, and it has the same author as the other events.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event's post status is likely set to sold_out, even if you've changed the ticket limits. There's actually a bug Event Espresso related its usage of a custom added "sold_out" post status, related to the issue reported here:

https://github.com/eventespresso/event-espresso-core/issues/278

So when it processes the GET request it sees that the event's post status isn't Published which leads to the unexpected the 403 error.